# Scraping using selenium error connection closed

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

im using selenium for scraping a website,but i got this error.what does this mean? am i blocked? what should i do to do scraping in that website..

> ```
> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
>   (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
> ```

this is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.implicitly_wait(10) #secs


# click "usd"

book = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"selectPeriod")))
sel = Select(book)
sel.select_by_value("range")

bookk = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_ddlmatauang1")))
sel = Select(bookk)
sel.select_by_value("USD  ")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

start_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtFrom")
start_date.send_keys("30-Des-20")
end_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtTo")
end_date.send_keys(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

time.sleep(5)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='Cari']")
buttons[1].click()
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given chrome  driver path when  calling method `webdriver.Chrome()` May be you have set environment path to chromedriver
I tried your code in windows machine and it worked for me by setting the driver path .

Try to manually set the path as shown below and check if issue persist. It may environment issue

```
driver_path = 'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
```

Please also check [link](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-closed/) for ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED, it is possible that chrome is not able to connect to internet, are you able to access website on chrome browser or do you need to set proxy  access internet??